# Is there a reverse function for local time in C?

Tags: c, linux

I have a string containing

`YYYY/MON/DATE-HR:MIN:SEC`

I want to get the individual values of all the fields, especially seconds filed in a TM structure.

Is there any function to do this conversion (or) any other way of achieving it?

Comment: You could look into [`strptime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime).

Comment: You could always try reading the documentation: http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime "See Also

date(1), gettimeofday(2), time(2), utime(2), clock(3), difftime(3), strftime(3), strptime(3), timegm(3), tzset(3), time(7) "

Comment: Use http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/date_time.html or just split the string to get the individual elements (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#idp432343152)

Comment: `strptime` is not a standard C function, but if your system doesn't have it you can download a freeware implementation.

Comment: `if (6 == sscanf(str, "%4d/%2d/%2d-%2d:%2d:%2d", &tm.tm_year, &tm.tm_mon,  ...) { tm.tm_year -= 1900; tm.tm_mon--; }`

Comment: Maybe a regular expression?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: `strptime()` is POSIX and Linux is POSIX, so as the question is tagged Linux it should  `strptime()` be avaliable. However it might be necessary to `#define` `_XOPEN_SOURCE`.

Answer (score 2):

Other way of achieving it (assuming `YYYY/MM/DD-HH:MM:SS`):

```
struct tm Str2Tm(const char* str)
{
    struct tm var = {0};
    var.tm_isdst = -1; // daylight saving time information is not available
    var.tm_year = 1000*(str[0]-'0')+100*(str[1]-'0')+10*(str[2]-'0')+1*(str[3]-'0')-1900;
    var.tm_mon  = 10*(str[ 5]-'0')+1*(str[ 6]-'0')-1;
    var.tm_mday = 10*(str[ 8]-'0')+1*(str[ 9]-'0');
    var.tm_hour = 10*(str[11]-'0')+1*(str[12]-'0');
    var.tm_min  = 10*(str[14]-'0')+1*(str[15]-'0');
    var.tm_sec  = 10*(str[17]-'0')+1*(str[18]-'0');
    return var;
}
```

If the month is in 3-letter format, then you will have to get `var.tm_mon` in a different way:

```
int GetMon(const char* str)
{
    static const char mon_name[][4] =
    {
        "Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"
    };
    for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
        if (str[5]==mon_name[i][0] && str[6]==mon_name[i][1] && str[7]==mon_name[i][2])
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: @chux: Thanks. I wasn't really sure about these three, so I initialized the entire structure to 0. Do I just need to set the first one to -1 then?

Comment: @chux: Thanks. I meant the three fields that you mentioned in your first comment.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using a `sscanf()`

```
void filltm(char* str , struct tm* tim)
{
    sscanf(str , "%d/%d/%d-%d:%d:%d" , &tim->tm_year , &tim->tm_mon , &tim->tm_mday , &tim->tm_hour , &tim->tm_min , &tim->tm_sec);
    tim->tm_year -= 1900;
    tim->tm_mon--;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple `sscanf()` solution with basic error checking.

```
struct tm tm = {0};  //Zero out all members
if (6 != sscanf(str, "%d/%d/%d-%d:%d:%d", 
    &tm.tm_year, &tm.tm_mon, &tm.tm_mday, 
    &tm.tm_hour, &tm.tm_min, &tm.tm_sec)) Handle_BadInput();
tm.tm_year -= 1900;
tm.tm_mon--;
tm.tm_isdst = -1;
if (mktime(&tm) == -1) Handle_OutOfRange();  // set tm_wday, tm_yday fields.
```

Comment: Perhaps last line should call `mktime` not `localtime` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes. Wrong function call.  Answer amended